# passing value from one page to another with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

How can I pass the value of textarea to a new page according to the `groupwall` method?
Here I just redirect the page. I want to make status update according to their semester.
Here is my code. Give me some code sample or suggest if this is not the right way to do that.

```
<form action=""   method="get">
    <textarea name="status" id="wall" cols="50" rows="2">                
    </textarea>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="share" onclick="groupwall();"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function groupwall(){
        var semster=document.getElementById('txtsamp').value;
        if(semster == "4-1"){
            window.location ='4-1hpage.php';
            //header("location: member-index.php");
        }
        else if(semster =="3-1"){
            window.location ='3-1hpage.php';
        }
        else if(semster == "2-1"){
            window.location ='2-1hpage.php';
        }
        else {
            window.location ='1-1hpage.php';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be better off posting the textarea content to your server and storing it somewhere, even in the session. the reason I say this is that while you could pass it in `window.location` as a `GET` parameter, the textarea content can be arbitrarily long and might be too long to be passed as a `GET` parameter. you might consider an AJAX request to post the textarea to the content, perhaps performing validation, before redirecting to the next page of your application.

Comment: so should i use database to store the content of textarea?

Comment: no, you could simply store it in the `$_SESSION` if it's something that's needed persisted temporarily while enroute to another part of the application

Answer (score 0):

Just give your form an id -
`<form id="share-form" ...`

Set the action of the form instead of redirecting

```
var share_form = document.getElementById('share-form');  
share_form.action = '....';
```

Submit the form
`share_form.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to pass some sort of variable to a new page if the data isn't large is to put it in a query string in the URL and then have the new page parse it out of there and act on it.  A query string is the  part of the URL that follows a question mark like this:

```
4-1hpage.php?data=whatever
```

The query string values don't affect which page is called on your server, but can be used by either server or client to trigger different behavior in that page.

In the specifics of your particular question, it doesn't seem like you need to pass any data to the next page because you're already called a different page based on the results of the textarea, but you could pass the value like this if you needed to:

```
function groupwall() {
    var semster=document.getElementById('txtsamp').value;
    var url;
    if(semster == "4-1") {
        url ='4-1hpage.php';
    } else if(semster =="3-1") {
        url ='3-1hpage.php';
    } else if(semster == "2-1") {
        url ='2-1hpage.php';
    } else {
        url ='1-1hpage.php';
    }
    // encode the data for URL safety and make sure it isn't too long
    window.location = url + "?semster=" + encodeURIComponent(semster.slice(0, 128));
}
```

If the textarea can be arbitrarily long and it needs to be capable of accepting very long values, then you will want to post it to your server and let the server decide where to redirect the user after the form post.  When generating a new page, the server can then populate that page with whatever content is needed based on the values in the form post.

Other places that data can be stored temporarily so a future page can access it are cookies and HTML5 local storage.  Cookies are somewhat restricted in size and it isn't efficient to put large data into cookies.  HTML5 local storage isn't supported in all browsers so you generally need an alternate strategy as a fallback.

Comment: textarea content could be very long and not suited to a query string parameter, don't you think?

Comment: @dldnh - it could be, but doesn't appear to be in this case.  It depends upon the application.  If it isn't too big, this is one of the simplest ways to pass it to a new page.

Comment: how can I get the data in next page??

Comment: @Subho - I'm not sure what you're asking, but it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question being asked here.  Please ask a new question that describes your own situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) do a form post to another PHP page and 
  a) Store it in a database   (If you will really use this in future also)
          OR
  b) Store it in Session Variable
          OR
2) do an ajax post to a server page and 
          OR
  a) Store it in a database
          OR
  b) Store it in Session Variable
```

Then from any PHP pages you can access these values.

Answer (score 0):

1. Send as a parameter through the query string `yoururl.com?variable=value`
2. Through `$_SESSION` environment variable
3. Using a cookie (if turned on)
4. AJAX - store in database or text file before leaving page, and retrieve when entering new page